# Why next function is called and when error funtion is called in the observer?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next('product some value');
      let x = 5;
      if(x == 5) {
        observer.error('something went wrong');
      }
      observer.complete();
    });

    observable.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
    },() => console.log('done'));
```

So when x is 5 I get this in console:

```
produce some value
something went wrong
```

and when x is not 5, I get what I should:

```
produce some value
done
```

Why in the first case when x is 5, and when I should only get "something went wrong" in the console, do I also get the value from the next function? How can I prevent this?

I started with RxJS because Angular uses it a lot, and I don't understand how in the background the HttpClient is configured to return observables in this way because there when there is some error it gets inside the error method only, if there is success with the HTTP request it gets in the next and complete methods only.

I am using Angular version 10 and RxJS version 6.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you get the value you passed to the next method? You emitted that *before* the error.

Comment: You first call `observer.next()` and then `observer.error()` so the `next` notification is propagated first

Comment: Okay, i thought it is automatically handled in the background.

Comment: How i can see how this is handled in the background in the http requests in angular ?

Comment: you can check httpClient definition in https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient
The only thing you need to know is that the httpClient methods will catch any error in your backend function and return it in the error callback when you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ty this:

```
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i === 5) {
      observer.error('something went wrong');
    }
    observer.next('product some value: ' + i);
  }

  observer.complete();
});

observable.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error:console.log,
  complete: () => console.log("done")
});
```

The output:

```
product some value: 0
product some value: 1
product some value: 2
product some value: 3
product some value: 4
something went wrong
```

See how **ONCE** you get an error, you don't get any more values? Before you get an error, emitted values are allowed.

---

HTTP requests only have one emission and then they complete. The result is that you get either

`next() & complete()`

or

`error()`

But that's just because there's only one emission. Observables can have any number of emissions before they error or complete. They can only error or complete once and they can only do one or the other. After they error or complete, they can no longer emit anything.

The results you were seeing are an emergent property of http requests, not a part of the obsevable contract.